# converting fingerprint template on android

Tags: android, arduino, fingerprint

I have a finger print scanner connected to an arduino which transmits data to android device through BT,the FPS has only a built in limited capacity of 200 fingerprints and i need a much higher capacity.Is there a way I can transform the fingerprint templates provided by the FPS directly on an android device to a string , number or byte ?

Answer (score 2):

FingerPrint sensor could produce picture of fingerprint or template (list of minutiae.
Template are created from picture by extracting minutiae.
Matching between 2 fingerprint are done on template.

So it's better to store template. It's required less storage and it's more faster (not need to extract minutiae at each match).

Picture could be converted in byte array.
Template are byte array.

Send us more details: What's fingerprint sensor ? Which Fingerprint SDK do you use ?

I have a look to your SDK and it look like a SDK I already used maybe it's another version. I never been able extract template in ISO format to use it outside sensor. And I never been able to extract template and re-inject it in sensor to use it to match.
But you have 2 methods
"DownChar" & "UpChar" to download and upload template in sensor.

Comment: I have an adafruit fingerprint scanner which has an in built arduino library for enrolling and matching templates. 
I am building my app using app inventor , is there an android software capable of matching 1:N templates ? or do I need to write the code on app inventor

Comment: So I managed to extract the array for each template, it looks something like:
Template 1 : 
0x239, 0x1, 0x255, 0x255, 0x255, 0x255, 0x2, 0x0, 0x130, 0x3, 0x1, 0x103, 0x12, 0x0, 0x0, 0x255, 
0x254, 0x255, 0x254, 0x225, 0x254, 0x128, 0x254, 0x0, 0x254, 0x0, 0x126, 0x0, 0x126, 0x0, 0x62, 0x0, 
0x62, 0x0, 0x62, 0x0, 0x62, 0x0, 0x159, 0x128, 0x62, 0x0, 0x62, 0x128, 0x62, 0x128, 0x30, 0x128, 
0x30, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 
0x118, 0x33, 0x155, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x239, 0x255, 0x6, 0x128, 0x31,
how can I convert this to a unique #

Comment: But , Can it be done? I mean matching 2 templates on android outside sensor ?

Comment: Yes but you need a standard format as "ANSI INCITS 378"  or "ISO 19794-2, FMC compact size". Because you only have proprietary format so it work's only inside sensor. Or maybe provider could give you SDK to do it outside sensor

Comment: This is the best I can get :
uint8_t Adafruit_Fingerprint::fingerFastSearch(void) {
fingerID = 0xFFFF;
confidence = 0xFFFF;
// high speed search of slot #1 starting at page 0x0000 and page #0x00A3
uint8_t packet[] = {FINGERPRINT_HISPEEDSEARCH, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA3};
writePacket(theAddress, FINGERPRINT_COMMANDPACKET, sizeof(packet)+2, packet);
uint8_t len = getReply(packet);
if ((len != 1) && (packet[0] != FINGERPRINT_ACKPACKET))
return -1;
fingerID = packet[2];
fingerID <<= 8;
fingerID |= packet[3];
confidence = packet[4];
confidence <<= 8;
confidence |= packet[5];
return packet[1];

Comment: Please share a link to doc